# box shadow doesn't display in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

interncup-thc.ucoz.com

Under Brackets, around the text it should have been a green shadow which on chrome/firefox displays but on IE doesn't. I have IE 10

What's wrong? trying to fix this for one day already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to change your HTML so that it detects if it is IE or not and applies a corresponding class as necessary. It will add a lot more to your CSS, but it is going to have to be necessary for IE compatibility.

If you want to cover all versions of IE Then you would do something like the following:

Replace your `<body>` tag with this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><body class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><body class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><body class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9) ]> <body class="modern"><![endif]-->
<!--[!(IE)]><!--><body class="notIE modern"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

And you would apply for example:

```
body.ie6 #box,
body.ie7 #box,
ody.ie8 #box {
/* This contains the color of the shadow in the CSS3 syntax */
    background: #cccccc;

 /* This contains the blur-radius in the CSS3 syntax */
zoom: 1;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=5);

  /* You must remove the border in IE, since it will be replaced in the next rule */
border: none;
```

Here is a very good reference on [How to Simulate CSS3 box-shadow in IE6-8 Without JavaScript.](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/)

Comment: He fleshed it out and made it a bit clearer to read, frankly.

Comment: @patrick Yeah? Made it easier to read by taking out Bolded sections? Seems pretty preferential to me, but to each his own.

Comment: hey, thanks for this relly helped me...meanwhile i've found a way easier fix for this, adding border-collapse: separate; to the TD style made it work on IE 10... until i make your fix work, i will let the IE fans suffer a little